# Correct permission to upload thumbnail to Dailymotion through API

Tags: dailymotion-api

Although my account is a Dailymotion Partner I can't upload custom thumbnail along with video.

As far as I can see from the API doc needs to have some permission to do this but which permission ?

https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is only available for our "verified partners". If you want to become one, pleae fill this form: [Partnership request](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=65053#new-request)